# How to get average value of Red channel from the UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, rgb, pixel

How can I get average value of Red channel from the UIImage.

Using this code I can find out what is the red channel value of the pixel (240,160)

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);


        int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width * 240) + 160) * 4; // The image is png

        UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];
```

What I am interested is to find the average of the red channel values from all the pixels of the whole image, or just a square part of the image.

Is this possible without using 320*480 calculations ?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the right thing. If you want the average, you'll have to add all the red channel's value in the area you are surveying. Even if you used a filter to isolate the red channel, it would essential add up to being the same thing. Going through the pixel buffer like you are doing is the fastest way in my opinion.

You might be able to optimize based on other information you have (how uniform is it for example) so you could reduce the size of the rectangle. Or you might be able to skip every other pixel for example (or more). I'd imagine that on a photo, this would yield an acceptable approximate result of the average. It would reduce the area you have to scan.

Just a thought to give you extra avenues...